# Reading external file

Tags: c++, c

I am doing the cpu scheduler simulator and I need it to read an external file. I have created the file in txt form, and have saved it to the desktop, the file contains numbers in the form -

```
12;3;5
3;4;2
3;4;5
```

I saved the file as input.txt on the desktop.
I tried reading through it using this code

```
FILE *fa;
fa= fopen("input.txt","r");
   if ((fa = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("input.txt file not found\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
while (fgets(line,1024, fa) != NULL)
{        
    e=k+1;
    sscanf(line,"%d;%d;%d\n",&num[0],&num[1],&num[2]);
    a[i][0]=num[0];
    printf("%d",&a[i][0]);
    a[i][1]=num[1];
    a[i][2]=num[2];
    a[i][3]=e;
    i++;
    k++;
  }
fclose(fa);
```

This code gives me an output which reads input.txt not found, and I don't know why.

Comment: you are trying to open same file twice.

Comment: Please... use proper variable names. While `i` is fine for a loop variable, `e` and `k` aren't really good.

Comment: Remark to improve your code and that's not an answer: try to use `fscanf` directly. This will avoid using both `fgets` and `sscanf`

Answer (score 1):

You're opening it twice. Also you might be running it with wrong working directory.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `fopen("input.txt","r");`, the library will assume a particular path for the file, it will be assumed to be in the current working directory, typically the same folder as the executable itself (in Windows/visual C++ ) or the location from where the exe is launched ( most unix based systems ) .

So unless the executable is on the desktop ( or the desktop is the current working directory ), this is the reason for the failure. The two ways to fix this are to either make the path absolute in someway, or to move the file to the expected working directory of the executable.

Comment: It assumes the current working directory, not the executable's directory.  They are not always the same (often on UNIX systems they are not).

Comment: @chmeee Yup, thats true, let me fix it.

Comment: @KarthikT@chmeee i am sorry but maybe am too much of an armature but how do i make the path absolute